# JsonTextReader.Read() and JObject.Load(jsonTextReader) mechanism

Tags: c#, token, streamreader, json, reference-type

I have the following code for reading a stream using a JsonTextReader and JObject.Load:

```
private void ProcessStream(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            while (jsonTextReader.Read())
            {
                if (jsonTextReader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                {
                    JObject jObject = JObject.Load(jsonTextReader);
                    /* Manipulate jObject */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, isn't the jsonTextReader pointer being moved forward twice or more times(leading to tokens being missed): once at jsonTextReader.Read() and one or more times in JObject.Load(jsonTextReader)? I couldn't find documentation explaining this detail regarding either JsonTextRead.Read() or JObject.Load. But peeking into JObject.Load(jsonTextReader) using Resharper shows there are multiple times where jsonTextReader.Read() is being called:

```
public new static JObject Load(JsonReader reader)
{
    ...
    while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
    {
        reader.Read();
    }

    ...
    JObject o = new JObject();
    o.SetLineInfo(reader as IJsonLineInfo);

    o.ReadTokenFrom(reader);

    return o;
}

internal void ReadTokenFrom(JsonReader reader)
{
    ...
    if (!reader.Read())
        throw JsonReaderException.Create(reader, "Error reading {0} from JsonReader.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, GetType().Name));

    ReadContentFrom(reader);

    ...
}

internal void ReadContentFrom(JsonReader r)
{
    ...
    do{

    } while (r.Read());
}
```

Is jsonTextReader being passed by value to JObject.Load()? If not, and if it is being passed by reference to Load()(which is usually the case for C# class objects), isn't this equivalent to Read() being called multiple times on jsonTextReader inside the while loop?

The fact is, the code seems to work. So the above explanation is incorrect. I am just not sure which part of the explanation is incorrect. Can someone please explain how the stream is being read token by token using both JSonTextReader.Read() and JObject.Load().

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where it's specifically documented, but this "off by one" behavior is consistently how JSON.NET works on reading.  Various internal functions that consume JsonReader expect their first symbol to consume to have been read already and be available for inspection, but when they finish they don't read in the next symbol after their last one.  It helps when writing recursive serialization handlers:  you can see the first symbol, and then make a decision from that on what method to pass the stream to.

In your example, after the call to JObject.Load, jsonTextReader.TokenType will be JsonToken.EndObject.